# Android Deactivation issue

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am getting the warning "Deactivation of this APK will result in your app being available for new installs on fewer types of devices." that i have seen on other questions, the difference with mine is that the min/max version values did not change at all.

New Version:

[image]

Old Version:

[image]

Why would it be warning me about this if nothing changed?

Comment: Something will have changed in your App's manifest to target fewer devices, but no-one can help you with out more information. Please include your old and new versions of your gradle build file and your Apps manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you flagged your basic version number to be 1.10.0? Please check your gradle files

Comment: Are you referring to something like this:

versionName "1.10.0"

Comment: No, but similarly have you set any flag for versionName to be only 1.10.0?